# Copy constructor and copy assignment operator?

Tags: c++

```
string func()
{
string s;
//do something with s
return s;
}
string mystr=func();
```

(This is not C++11)
In the above example, I understand that the copy constructor of `string` will be called when it is returned, however, in this example, will the copy assignment operator of `string` also be called when `mystr` get its value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string mystr=func();
```

does not invoke the copy assignment operator. It initializes `mystr` using the copy constructor.

To invoke the copy assignment operator, the initialization and assignment need to be two separate statements.

```
string mystr;
mystr = func();
```

Answer (score 0):

No. The code you posted so far does not involve `string`'s copy assignment operator in any shape, way or form.